# When I try to run Tum-rgbd dataset on ORM-SLAM3, cv::Mat always make the memory leaked

Tags: c++, opencv, out-of-memory

```
Loading ORB Vocabulary. This could take a while...
Vocabulary loaded!

Initialization of Atlas from scratch
Creation of new map with id: 0
Creation of new map with last KF id: 0
Seq. Name:
There are 1 cameras in the atlas
Camera 0 is pinhole

-------

Start processing sequence ...
Images in the sequence: 3615

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
./tum_examples.sh: line 7: 63996 Aborted
```

And my code is below:

```
    cout << endl << "-------" << endl;
    cout << "Start processing sequence ..." << endl;
    cout << "Images in the sequence: " << nImages << endl << endl;

    // Main loop
    cv::Mat imRGB, imD;
    for(int ni=0; ni<nImages; ni++)
    {
        // After my investigation, it was found that there was a problem with cv:: Mat
        imRGB = cv::imread(string(argv[3])+"/"+vstrImageFilenamesRGB[ni],cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED); //,cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
        imD = cv::imread(string(argv[3])+"/"+vstrImageFilenamesD[ni],cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED); //,cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
        double tframe = vTimestamps[ni];

        if(imRGB.empty())
        {
            cerr << endl << "Failed to load image at: "
                 << string(argv[3]) << "/" << vstrImageFilenamesRGB[ni] << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        if(imageScale != 1.f)
        {
            int width = imRGB.cols * imageScale;
            int height = imRGB.rows * imageScale;
            cv::resize(imRGB, imRGB, cv::Size(width, height));
            cv::resize(imD, imD, cv::Size(width, height));
        }

#ifdef COMPILEDWITHC11
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
#else
        std::chrono::monotonic_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::monotonic_clock::now();
#endif

        // Pass the image to the SLAM system
        SLAM.TrackRGBD(imRGB,imD,tframe);

#ifdef COMPILEDWITHC11
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
#else
        std::chrono::monotonic_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::monotonic_clock::now();
#endif

        double ttrack= std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(t2 - t1).count();

        vTimesTrack[ni]=ttrack;

        // Wait to load the next frame
        double T=0;
        if(ni<nImages-1)
            T = vTimestamps[ni+1]-tframe;
        else if(ni>0)
            T = tframe-vTimestamps[ni-1];

        if(ttrack<T)
            usleep((T-ttrack)*1e6);
    }
```

After my investigation, it was found that there was a problem with cv::Mat，but I don't kown the reason.Additionally, my input's format is png and my opencv version is 3.4.14.

I've tried to reinstall opencv version form 4.4.0 to 3.4.14, and tried the test demo on Euroc dataset which has been worked on ORB-SLAM3.I hope someone could give some advice,thank you a lot!

Comment: Please provide a [mre] if you need debugging help